# Solr FilterQuery - using AND and NOT in a query

Tags: solr

A document in solr cloud is like

```
{
 currentcompany : ACME; //text_general
 previouscompanies : Infosys, Hexaware; // text_general multivalued
 post: some string here //text_general probably irrelevant but could be 
       used to replicate my schema. this is the default field
}
```

When passing a query like

```
{

 q = *:*;
 fq = {!cache=false}((currentcompany:((ACME OR HDFC OR ICICI) 
      AND (!AIRTEL))) OR (previouscompanies:((LCMS OR HEXAWARE) AND (!LOMBARD))));

 }
```

I am getting empty result. Can someone help me understand why this is so.

More Info:

df : post //Default field.  It is a text_general. 
 when passing either of these, I'm getting the result:

```
{

 q = *:*;
 fq = {!cache=false}((currentcompany:((ACME OR HDFC OR ICICI) 
      AND (!AIRTEL))) OR (previouscompanies:((LCMS OR HEXAWARE))));

} //removed  AND (!LOMBARD)


{

 q = *:*;
 fq = {!cache=false}((currentcompany:((ACME OR HDFC OR ICICI)
      OR (previouscompanies:((LCMS OR HEXAWARE) AND (!LOMBARD))));

} //removed AND (!AIRTEL)))
```

EDIT: Sorry. The fields are current company & previous companies.

Update: The following query works

```
{!cache=false}((currentcompany:((ACME OR HDFC OR ICICI) 
              AND !(AIRTEL))) OR (previouscompanies:((LCMS OR HEXAWARE) 
              AND !(LOMBARD)))); //Used the not operator outside the bracket
```

Solves my problem, but still curious why the previous format didn't work.

QueryParser is edismax.

Comment: what is your default operator in config? i also assume, that you mess up fields currentdisignation and currentcompany

Comment: could you also share your schema.xml

Comment: @Mysterion hi the default operator in config is OR and I'm using solr could and new to it. I tried searching for schema.xml but cant find it. Even tried using the locate tool. I am guessing solr cloud uses only config api. If I'm mistaken, kindly point me to path and I'll share it :)

Comment: @Mysterion any thoughts based on the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets talk about your the first part of your **correct** query:

```
(currentcompany:((ACME OR HDFC OR ICICI) AND !(AIRTEL)))
```

Here the idea is to select all the documents that have `currentcompany` in `ACME`, `HDFC`, `ICICI` but not `AIRTEL`.

There is no need to specify the not `AIRTEL` part, you have already specified the list of allowed values (which incidentally does not comprise `AIRTEL`).

Now I have to do an important premise, when you use the `AND` operator in a Solr filter query is like to select the intersection between two groups of documents.

So again, lets try to take only the first part of the **wrong** query:

```
(currentcompany:((ACME OR HDFC OR ICICI) AND (!AIRTEL)))
```

Here you're trying to intersect two sets, the former is the set of documents where `currentcompany` is in `ACME`, `HDFC`, `ICICI` and the latter is an empty set.

The intersection between a set and an empty set always returns an empty set, that's why Solr does not return any document.

When you use the NOT operator within the brackets you have an empty set, this because

> Solr only checks to see if the top level query is a pure negative
>   query

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/NegativeQueryProblems

So you cannot use the NOT operator in side the brackets in this way, you should try with `(*:* AND NOT AIRTEL)`, this sets is not empty and selects all the documents that not have `currentcompany` equals to `AIRTEL`. But as said, this make no sense, because you've already selected the list of allowed `currentcompany`.

Comment: thanks. fixed the question. the fields are currentcompany and previouscompanies.

Comment: Hi @Cybermonk, I've read your update yesterday, but few things are missing, for example: what version of Solr you're using. Anyway I'll try to create a collection with document you posted using the default text_general in Solr 7.1.0 and see what happens with the queries you've posted.

Comment: Thanks. Using Solr 7.1.0 the document schema (added field post) mentioned above is like how it is in my setup

Comment: Thanks a lot. brilliant answer, expanded my understanding of solr.